# Adding condition inside HTML

Tags: html, sql, oracle, html-email

I am sending an HTML message to send_email functionality from stored procedure.
HTML content is stored as a template in a table and the dynamic values are passed to this table which renders the display.
All this is done from the stored procedure which calles SMTP open connection.

This is how the body is formed inside the Stored procedure.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                REGEXP_REPLACE(
                REGEXP_REPLACE( 
                REGEXP_REPLACE(body, '<DUE_DAYS> business days',v_past_due)                                  
                                   , '<COMPANY_ADDRESS>', p_email(indx).address||'<BR/>'
                                                        ||p_email(indx).city||', '
                                                        ||p_email(indx).state||' '
                                                        ||p_email(indx).zip)                                  
                                   , '<TAX_PIN>', TO_CHAR(p_email(indx).tax_pin,'$9G999G999G990D00'))
                                   , '<TAX_AMT>', TO_CHAR(p_email(indx).tax_amt,'$9G999G999G990D00'))
                                   , '<TAX_AMT_PEN>', TO_CHAR(p_email(indx).tax_amt_pen,'$9G999G999G990D00'))
                                   , '<DUE_DATE>' , due_date)
           INTO v_body
           FROM pmail_txt
          WHERE status = 'DUE_SEND';
```

The html content in pmail_txt for status = 'DUE_SEND' looks like this,

```
<TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH="75%;"><TBODY>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Overall Due Days:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><v_past_due></TD></TR>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Company Address:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><COMPANY_ADDRESS></TD></TR>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Pin Number:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><TAX_PIN></TD></TR>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Amount Due:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><TAX_AMT></TD></TR><TR>
<TD WIDTH="40%">Ex Amount Due:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><EIND_AMT></TD></TR>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%"><STRONG>Pendign Amount Due</STRONG>:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><STRONG><TAX_AMT_PEN></STRONG></TD></TR>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%"><STRONG>Due DATE</STRONG>:</TD><TD WIDTH ="60%"><STRONG><DUE_DATE></STRONG></TD></TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

I want a condition to be added to the HTML such that when  value is null do not show the field in the email body.

I have changed the code as per comment below. I get it work for not null fields however for for empty fields/null body of the message doesnt appear at all. Can someone tell me where i went wrong?

```
<style>
.hidden_v_past_due  {
display:none;
}
</style>
    <TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH="75%;"><TBODY>
    <TR class="hidden_v_past_due<v_past_due>"><TD WIDTH="40%">Overall Due Days:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><v_past_due></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Company Address:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><COMPANY_ADDRESS></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Pin Number:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><TAX_PIN></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Amount Due:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><TAX_AMT></TD></TR><TR>
    <TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Ex Amount Due:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><EIND_AMT></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD WIDTH="40%"><STRONG>Pendign Amount Due</STRONG>:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><STRONG><TAX_AMT_PEN></STRONG></TD></TR>
    <TR><TD WIDTH="40%"><STRONG>Due DATE</STRONG>:</TD><TD WIDTH ="60%"><STRONG><DUE_DATE></STRONG></TD></TR>
    </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
```

Also tried scriplet like below

```
<TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH="75%;"><TBODY>
<%if(v_past_due != null){%>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Overall Due Days:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><v_past_due></TD></TR><%}%>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Company Address:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><COMPANY_ADDRESS></TD></TR>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Pin Number:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><TAX_PIN></TD></TR>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Amount Due:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><TAX_AMT></TD></TR><TR>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%">Ex Amount Due:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><EIND_AMT></TD></TR>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%"><STRONG>Pendign Amount Due</STRONG>:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><STRONG><TAX_AMT_PEN></STRONG></TD></TR>
<TR><TD WIDTH="40%"><STRONG>Due DATE</STRONG>:</TD><TD WIDTH ="60%"><STRONG><DUE_DATE></STRONG></TD></TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

tried below options too

```
<%if(<v_past_due>){%>....///......<%}%>
<%if(v_past_due != null){%>....///......<%}%>
```

All these work for !null condition and everything fails for null.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a class attribute to  element such as when the corresponding field value is null the resulting class name will hide the element.  E.g.

```
<style>
.hidde_v_past_due {
display:none;
}
</style>
...
<TR class="hidde_v_past_due<v_past_due>"><TD WIDTH="40%">Overall Due Days:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><v_past_due></TD></TR>
```

In this way, when v_past_due is empty then the class name will match the one in the style and your TR will not display.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But where do you add these script? in the DB? Would it allow? Still you need to check for the null condition right.

Comment: You include it in the HTML content, as part of your template .  You don't need to check for the null condition, because if your value is empty then the resulting HTML will be affected by the style rule.  Check this example  https://jsfiddle.net/tzyctfvj/

Comment: Looks like the style works because i dont see the particular field however its hidden for all conditions which means it doesnt work for null condition. this is the code i added         <TR class="hidde_v_past_due<TAX_AMT_PEN>"><TD WIDTH="40%"><STRONG>Pendign Amount Due</STRONG>:</TD><TD WIDTH="60%"><STRONG><TAX_AMT_PEN></STRONG></TD></TR>

Comment: any help appreciated.

Comment: Consider that you are replacing any ocurrency of variables  in template.  Following the example above, any TR element having the class "hidde_v_past_due" is going to be hidden.  That's the purpose of appending the same value to the class attr, when that value is not empty, then the resulting class is going to be different and hence the style rule will not apply. In other words, only when the value of variable is empty then the TR element will not be visible.